# send parameters to setUp

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am writing some unit tests, before each test I init some seed data in the db. here is my example code which works:

```
import unittest

class TestLogin(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        init_db()

    def test_login1(self):
        test_something()

    def test_login2(self):
        test_something()
```

I would like to send parameters to the setup, each text should be initialized with some other user, something like:

```
import unittest

class TestLogin(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self, params) -> None:
        init_db(params.user)

    @param(user='jim')
    def test_login1(self):
        test_something()

    @param(user='bob')
    def test_login2(self):
        test_something()
```

How can I parameterize the setup for each test case?

Comment: Why not just do e.g. `init_db('jim')` inside the relevant test?

Comment: The whole idea of setup is to deduplicate things that are shared by all of the tests. Things that are specific to a case should be _in that case_. If the example isn't representative of the actual problem you could give a better one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setUpClass` *classmethod* from the *unittest.TestCase* object.
This method will be launched  only one time by class object and will parametrize your setup by adding an intermediate instance variable.
You can access at the function name as a value of the variable `_testMethodName` from `self`.

So I think the better way to do that is

```py
import unittest


class TestLogin(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.users = {'test_login1': 'jim', 'test_login2': 'bob'}
        # Add params for your tests

    def setUp(self):
        user = self.users[self._testMethodName]
        # initialize your db
        # example: init_db(user)
        print(user)

    def test_login1(self):
        print("l1")
        # Assert something

    def test_login2(self):
        print("l2")
        # Assert something
```

Comment: Thanks! this can be a solution, the only issue is that it is not test customized, for example if someone changes the test name, he might forget to change the key in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

I ended using [parameterized](https://github.com/wolever/parameterized)

```
import unittest2
from parameterized import parameterized_class

@parameterized_class(('username'), [
   ('jim'),
   ('bob')
])
class MyTest(unittest2.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        some_setup(self.username)

    def TestLogin(self):
        assert_something(self.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `setUpClass()` + `tearDownClass()` + [parameterized](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/). Here is an example:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from parameterized import parameterized


class TestLogin(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        # init_db() before tests, blablabla...
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls) -> None:
        # clear_db() after tests, blablabla...
        pass

    @parameterized.expand([
        ('jim', 'valid_password', 200),
        ('bob', 'invalid_password', 403),
    ])
    def test_login(self, user: str, password: str, expected: int):
        # status_code = requests.post(...).status_code
        # let's say the test always passes
        status_code = expected
        self.assertEqual(status_code, expected)
```

In this case you don't need to create `test_login1`, `test_login2`, ... etc. They will be created automatically using the parameters:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

...::TestLogin::test_login_0_jim PASSED                     [ 50%]
...::TestLogin::test_login_1_bob PASSED                     [100%]

============================== 2 passed in 0.02s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: thanks! how can I access the parameters on the `setup` function?
can you provide it in your code example?

Comment: `setUpClass()` / `tearDownClass()` are used to prepare / destroy everything needed for all test methods. In this case, you are not preparing something specific for each test. You can do it inside specific test using `parameter` as `argument` if you need.

Comment: see my example code in the question, Im using `setUp` not `setUpClass`

Comment: @dina I see. As I know, `setUp()` works before each test method. It means `init_db` etc will calls each time before each test. `setUpClass()` only works once before all tests and `setUp()`